# In Maxwell equations, why time derivatives only appear together with Curl?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, lorentz-symmetry

In the four maxwell's equations, the time dependence only appear in curl of $E$ and $B$ but not divergence.

My question was that:

1. Why time dependence only appear in curl?
2. what's the implication?

(I was thinking there was actually a fifth equation, continuum equation, which appear in divergence. Thus divergence was dependence in space while divergence was the symmetric relation in time.)

Comment: This is a great question an deserves a deep answer. Check out the covariant formulation of Maxwell's equation.

Comment: As an aside:  the continuity equation follows from the four Maxwell's equations (combine the time derivative of Gauss's Law with the divergence of Ampère's Law), so it doesn't really have the status of a "fifth equation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question that is ultimately tied to Lorentz symmetry. [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity) on tensor form read
$$ \sum_{\mu=0}^3\partial_{\mu} F^{\mu\nu}~\propto~ j^{\nu}_e, \qquad \sum_{\mu=0}^3\partial_{\mu} \widetilde{F}^{\mu\nu}~\propto~ j^{\nu}_m, \qquad \nu~\in~\{0,1,2,3\},$$ 
where we could not resist to introduce magnetic monopoles to make E&M duality manifest.

There are two cases:

1. Index $\nu=0$ is temporal: There are no time-derivatives $\partial_{\mu=0}$ since the $F$-tensor is anti-symmetric.
2. Index $\nu=j\in~\{1,2,3\}$ is spatial: Then there are two types of terms
   $$\partial_{0} F^{0j} + \sum_{i=1}^3\partial_i F^{ij}~\propto~ j^{j}_e. $$
   The first term has a time-derivative. In the second term
   the spatial-spatial components of the $F$-tensor are associate with an Levi-Civita epsilon-tensor, so that the spatial derivative becomes a curl. This is the answer to OP's question.

Comment: The answer to the question is that having a time derivate only where it actually occurs is the only way the equations can be invariant under Lorentz transformations. Your answer is correct but somehow hides the reason as if it were due to some tensor property, which is not the case (the universe could have been otherwise and we would have introduced an equally good new formalism).

Comment: @Qmechanic I know it is somewhat late, but isn't this post hoc reasoning? If I understood correctly you claim that the time derivatives arise from the antisymmetric nature of the Faraday tensor, but, as gented seems to suggest, in reality we only gave EM a tensor description after the transformation properties were understood. I don't see how it ties in to OP's question, albeit the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Faraday's law $$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=-\partial_t\mathbf{B}$$ is the differential form of the flux rule explored by Faraday: $\mathcal{E}=\dot{\Phi}$. Where $\mathcal{E}$ is the electromotive force $\mathcal{E}=\oint\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$ and $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux $\Phi=\iint\mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{A}$. The divergence equation (Gauss's law) is essentially a statement of the law of conservation of energy and can be derived from coulomb's law.

Ampere's law$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}$$ historically did not have a time-derivative. It is derived from the Biot-Savart law but as such does not satisfy the vector identity $\nabla\cdot\nabla\times\mathbf{v}=0$ but rather $\nabla\cdot\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\nabla\cdot\mathbf{J}$. This is resolved by plugging in Gauss's law into the continuity equation:
$$-\partial_t\rho=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{J}$$
$$-\epsilon_0\nabla\cdot\partial_t\mathbf{E}=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{J}$$
Thus the additive inverse is combined with $\mathbf{J}$, giving $$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}+\mu_0\epsilon_0\partial_t\mathbf{E}$$

Now, by taking the second curl of those equations (and assuming vacuum conditions), one can show that the electromagnetic field satisfies the wave equation with velocity $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}}=c$, a starting point for Einstein's relativity.